# Fade in bars one by one with D3

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, coffeescript

I have a bar chart and want to add effect to fade bars one by one with some delay.
Here is what I have now but it fades in all bars that are `path` at once. How can I make them appear one after another with some delay?

```
.selectAll("path")
.attr "opacity", (d,i)->
        0
.transition().delay(3000).duration(1000)
.attr "opacity", (d,i)->
        1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**

Use the index value to stagger the delay

```
 .delay(function(d,i){return i * 300;})
```

Because the index is zero based this means the first item has no delay. If this is not desired then you could do something like something like

```
 .delay(function(d,i){return (1+i) * 300;})
```

---

**Example**

For those less familiar with D3 a quick example of this in action at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KDET/)

Comment: Great, thanks! I knew I should have dig into delay options but couldn't figure out from which side.